# Linux (Raspbian) autostart script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Unfortunately I am completely green regarding Linux. I have some PYTHON scripts that needs to be running in the background. I created a simple script that runs them:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to start all custom applications
echo "Starting..."
sudo python /home/pi/scripts/info_memory.py &
sudo python /home/pi/scripts/info_relay.py &
sudo python /home/pi/scripts/info_temp_ext.py &
sudo python /home/pi/scripts/load_lifesign.py &
sudo python /home/pi/scripts/load_memory.py &
sudo python /home/pi/scripts/load_relay.py &
sudo python /home/pi/scripts/load_temp_ext.py &
```

If I start it with `sudo bash /home/pi/scripts/autorun.sh` everything works as expected.

I would like to automatically start my autorun.sh after reboot. I tried to add `sudo bash /home/pi/scripts/autorun.sh` to crontab (and sudo crontab) and also tried to add it to rc.local. In some cases nothing were started, some cases not all scripts were running.

Do you have any idea what could be wrong? TVM!

Comment: might be this blogpost I posted in past help you https://rahulmahale.wordpress.com/2014/09/03/solved-running-cron-job-at-reboot-on-raspberry-pi-in-debianwheezy-and-raspbian/

Comment: I dont know about raspbian but, adding sleep between lines may help. like: ( sleep 1 && python foo.py)
also why dont you add create some log file from script: echo someInfo >> log it helps debugging a lot.

Comment: The blogpost is very helpful. The script "autorun.sh" definitely starts (i checked the results with "htop"). Although I experience a strange behaviour: If I start the script manually, everything work fine, all the 7 scripts are started. If I cron starts "autorun.sh", 2 of the scripts are not started. I try to find out what could be the difference between working and not working scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks again both of you. I added another sleep at the beginning of my script and now it starts everything nicely.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting..."
sleep 30
sudo python /home/pi/scripts/info_relay.py &
sleep 5
sudo python /home/pi/scripts/info_memory.py &
sleep 5
sudo python /home/pi/scripts/info_temp_ext.py &
sleep 5
sudo python /home/pi/scripts/load_lifesign.py &
sleep 5
sudo python /home/pi/scripts/load_memory.py &
sleep 5
sudo python /home/pi/scripts/load_relay.py &
sleep 5
sudo python /home/pi/scripts/load_temp_ext.py &
```

Finally I removed /etc/init.d/cron/start from rc.local and it still works.